# Error reading file into array

Tags: c#, filestream

I get the following error on the second iteration of my loop:
 `Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.`

and this is my loop

```
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("D:\\06.Total Eclipse Of The Moon.mp3", FileMode.Open);

    byte[] _FileName = new byte[1024];
    long _FileLengh = fs.Length;

    int position = 0;

    for (int i = 1024; i < fs.Length; i += 1024)
    {
        fs.Read(_FileName, position, Convert.ToInt32(i));

        sck.Client.Send(_FileName);
        Thread.Sleep(30);

        long unsend = _FileLengh - position;

        if (unsend < 1024)
        {
            position += (int)unsend;
        }
        else
        {
            position += i;
        }
    }
    fs.Close();
}

fs.Length = 5505214
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On the first iteration, you're calling

```
fs.Read(_FileName, 0, 1024);
```

That's fine (although why you're calling `Convert.ToInt32` on an `int`, I don't know.)

On the second iteration, you're going to call

```
fs.Read(_FileName, position, 2048);
```

which is trying to read into the `_FileName` byte array starting at `position` (which is non-zero) *and fetching up to 2048 bytes*. The byte array is only 1024 bytes long, so that can't *possibly* work.

Additional problems:

- You haven't used a `using` statement, so on exceptions you'll leave the stream open
- You're ignoring the return value from `Read`, which means you don't know how much of your buffer has *actually* been read
- You're unconditionally sending the socket the complete buffer, regardless of how much has been read.

Your code should probably look more like this:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("D:\\06.Total Eclipse Of The Moon.mp3"))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        sck.Client.Send(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        // Do you really need this?
        Thread.Sleep(30);
    }
}
```

Comment: fs.Read(_FileName, position, 2048); << position = 1024, 2048 - 1024 = 1024 so my _FileName = 1024 there is enough space for that

Comment: @Acid: But you're saying that you want to start reading at index 1024 of `_FileName`. There *is* no such index - the last index of the array is 1023. Please read the documentation for `Stream.Read` - I don't think you understand what the second and third parameters are there for.

Comment: The last sentence actually made me notice that I missinterpreted the `offset` parameter. Thought it was related to the source stream, not the buffer. Helped me to fix a critical bug, thanks!